# How to prevent additional user from sharing SMS?

Tags: sms, multi-user, google-pixel-4a

I have a Google Pixel 4A 5G phone running Android 13. I added an additional user with System -> Multiple Users and enabled calls and SMS for the user. I am surprised that my messages are shared with the user. The documentation states that messages and apps are not shared. I chatted with Google Support but the person wasn't helpful. How do I prevent my messages from being shared with the additional user?

See https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/2865944?hl=en which states the following:

[image]

Comment: You *enabled calls and **SMS** for the user*  so why are you **surprised** ? (*I am surprised that my messages are shared with the user*)

Comment: Are you talking about that messages that has been received in the past are shared or just new messages that are received after you created the additional user?

Comment: Both messages I received in the past as well as any new messages I receive are shared with the additional user.  See https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/2865944?hl=en which states, Files and messages, like texts, email, photos, music, and more are not shared.